# Flutter path access exception creation failed, path = '/storage/emulated/0/HomeSchooling'

Tags: flutter, permission-denied

I am try to save Pdf and it is on saving on android 10 but not on new android verions
I have added these persmission in androidmanifest also

and in application tag this

android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"

but still not working on new android devices

static savePdf(String fileName, pdf.Document pdf) async {

```
Directory? directory;
try {
  if (Platform.isAndroid) {
    if (await requestPermission(Permission.storage)) {
      directory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
      String newPath = "";
      List<String> paths = directory!.path.split("/");
      for (int x = 1; x < paths.length; x++) {
        String folder = paths[x];
        if (folder != "Android") {
          newPath += "/$folder";
        } else {
          break;
        }
      }
      newPath = "$newPath/HomeSchooling";
      directory = Directory(newPath);
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  } else {
    if (await requestPermission(Permission.photos)) {
      directory = await getTemporaryDirectory();
    } else {

      return false;
    }
  }

  if (!await directory.exists()) {
    await directory.create(recursive: true);
  }
  if (await directory.exists()) {
    File saveFile = File("${directory.path}/$fileName.pdf");
    await saveFile.writeAsBytes(await pdf.save());
    await OpenFile.open(saveFile.path);
    return true;
  }
} catch (e) {
  pShowToast(message: e.toString());
  if (kDebugMode) {
    print(e.toString());
  }
  if (kDebugMode) {
    print(e);
  }
}
```

}